# Join considering length of characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to do a left join based on the number of characters. In the destination_postal_code column I hace a more deailed postcode value. In the dest_postal_code_prefix I have only the first few digits of a postcode. When I join I would like to output to consider this:

```
destination_postal_code     dest_postal_code_prefix
2345                        23
3356                        33
5672                        567
```

For now I have :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
p.destination_postal_code
FROM posimorders.atrops_ddl.o_slam_packages p
LEFT JOIN posimorders.sc_execution_eu.o_transit_time_pad t
ON p.destination_postal_code = t.dest_postal_code_prefix
```

The expected output would be

```
destination_postal_code 
2345                        
3356                        
5672
```

In the output it can be seen that, when my prefix is 23, I want all psotcodes begining with 23.. to be in mu output and so on

Comment: Are the prefixes distinct? I.e. do you have prefixes like `23`,`236`,`237`? Code `2368` could match to `23` and `236` - what are the requirements?

Comment: I have prefixes like 23 that should match with anything begining with 23....I also can have prefixes 236 that should match with anything with 236....The output should have distinct values in any case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your prefixes don't overlap, then you can just use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.destination_postal_code, t.dest_postal_code_prefix
FROM posimorders.atrops_ddl.o_slam_packages p LEFT JOIN
     posimorders.sc_execution_eu.o_transit_time_pad t
     ON p.destination_postal_code LIKE t.dest_postal_code_prefix || '%';
```

However, if they overlap (say "12" and "123"), then you probably want the longest one.  In that case, use aggregation along with `LIKE`:

```
SELECT p.destination_postal_code, MAX(t.dest_postal_code_prefix) as dest_postal_code_prefix
FROM posimorders.atrops_ddl.o_slam_packages p LEFT JOIN
     posimorders.sc_execution_eu.o_transit_time_pad t
     ON p.destination_postal_code LIKE t.dest_postal_code_prefix || '%'
GROUP BY p.destination_postal_code;
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this, using the LIKE operator:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
p.destination_postal_code, t.dest_postal_code_prefix
FROM posimorders.atrops_ddl.o_slam_packages p
LEFT JOIN posimorders.sc_execution_eu.o_transit_time_pad t
ON p.destination_postal_code like t.dest_postal_code_prefix||'%';
```

If you have overlap, you might want to have the longest matches first:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
p.destination_postal_code, t.dest_postal_code_prefix
FROM posimorders.atrops_ddl.o_slam_packages p
LEFT JOIN posimorders.sc_execution_eu.o_transit_time_pad t
ON p.destination_postal_code like t.dest_postal_code_prefix||'%'
ORDER BY LENGTH(t.dest_postal_code_prefix) DESC
;
```